# Lyapunov stability check

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stability-in-odes, stability-theory, lyapunov-functions

It is stated that for a system $\dot{x}=f(x)$ asymptotic stability is true if there is a Lyapunov function $V(x)$ such that $V(x)$ is positive definite and its time derivative is negative definite. My question is, isn't it possible that $V(x)$ is always decreasing but does not converge to zero but rather to certain asymptote. For example, is it possible that we have 2D parabola, and $V$ is always decreasing along some spiral path but its rate of decrease is also decreasing by time and goes to zero when time goes to infinity. And eventually $V$ goes to some circular path (asymptote).

Comment: This is possible only if we have $\dot{V}$ is zero on the asymptote. But this contradicts $\dot{V}$ being negative definite.

Comment: Do you also assume that the Lyapunov function is also radially unbound?

Comment: Does it make any difference?

Comment: If the level sets $\{x:\; V(x)=C\}$ are bounded (or, in other words, $V$ is radially unbounded), this is impossible - see the proof of the Lyapunov asymptotic stability theorem